# You could have told me that he had taken the taxi

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, past-perfect, british-english

"You could have told me that he had taken the taxi back home" Is this grammatically correct? By the way "had taken" is not used here as back shift of "has taken". "Had taken" is used for past happening here

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically correct and idiomatic.

Comment: It's "grammatical", but I don't think it's *that* "idiomatic". I'm sure the vast majority of native speakers would use Simple Past in this context: *You could have told me that he **took** a taxi home*.

Comment: ...in some cases, such as [*You could have told me you were bisexual and HIV positive*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+could+have+told+me+you+were+bisexual%22), it's virtually impossible to imagine anyone using Past Perfect. It's also worth pointing out that Google Books has plenty of hits for *you could have told me you **were...***. But there are no results I can read in context for *you could have told me you **had...***, so I can't even check to see if they're Past Perfect or not.

Comment: Not the topic, but the attachment of "back home" could be either to *told* or *had taken*.

Comment: Very unlikely that a native would use past perfect here. Tense is not as important in speaking English as you have probably been told. Native speakers don't much care.

Comment: @fumblefingers. I understood that it's better to use past tense "took the taxi" rather than "had taken the taxi" because "had taken taxi" cannot stand alone for past happening but don't you think that present happening which is "has taken the taxi" will be backshifted and will become "had taken the taxi"?

Comment: @John Lawler. I understood that it's better to use past tense "took the taxi" rather than "had taken the taxi" because "had taken taxi" cannot stand alone for past happening but don't you think that present happening which is "has taken the taxi" will be backshifted and will become "had taken the taxi"?

Comment: I don't recognise the concept *"had taken taxi" cannot stand alone for past happening*. Unless what you mean is Past Perfect is only valid if the current "narrative focus" identifies some point in past time relative to which the Perfect reference came ***before***. In the cited context this just means "he" took the taxi some time before the time at which addressee could have told the speaker that he had taken it (or that he took it, both verbs are syntactically / logically fine). It's a stylistic choice, where as John says, native speakers don't care much which choice we make.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes by "stand alone" i meant that past perfect is only valid if the action was already completed before any other action in past. Anyway What i understood is "had taken a taxi" was already completed before "You could have told me" so that's why we do not require any other past action. Kindly correct me if i understood you right.

Comment: Yes, it sounds to me like you've correctly understood the Past Perfect *requires* that the narrative / conversational context must have already established a "reference time" ***in the past***, so that the *perfect* verb form can be used to refer to things that [had] happened ***earlier***. But as also indicated by John Lawler, just because a context "allows" the Past Perfect doesn't mean native speakers will always actually ***use*** it. There's always a tendency to use the simplest possible verb form in many contexts where different versions are at least "acceptable".